# VBA Excel Dynamic Form Creation

Tags: vba, excel

Question: I have a form I created in Excel (Developer mode).  The form has a MutliPage control on it.  I am able to add a dynamically add new Page to the multipage control with VBA.  I have no idea how to add any content onto this page that I have just created - for example adding a new checkbox, labels etc.

The only code I have at the moment is:

```
DataQueryForm.DimensionTabs.Pages.Add "MyName", "My Caption"
Dim currentPage As Page
Set currentPage = DataQueryForm.DimensionTabs.Pages(0) 'this line fails
```

As you can see I don't even know how to get the first Page into a variable of type Page - so it's hard to know how to begin.

Any pointers in how to add new checkboxes to the page would be most appreciated. I'm really struggling to find decent documentation on this, really, anything at this stage would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `MSForms.Page` so you don't get a type mismatch (Excel also has a `Page` object) and you can set the variable as you add the page:

```
Dim currentPage As MSForms.Page
Set currentPage = DataQueryForm.Dimensiontabs.Pages.Add("MyName", "My Caption")
```

Comment: Yes, thanks!  And then I have access to Controls.Add method. currentPage.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "cmd1")